# not sure how to use php soap api

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to use this wsdl with PHP's  built-in SoapClient:

http://api1.silverpop.com/SoapApi?wsdl

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. My code:

```
<?php
$silverpop = new SoapClient('SoapApi.xml');
$result = $silverpop->Login(array('USERNAME' => 'zzz', 'PASSWORD' => 'xxx'));

echo $silverpop->__getLastRequest();
```

I'd expect the last request to be echo'd out but instead nothing is echo'd out making me question whether or not anything was actually sent out. Any ideas?

edit: I also tried this without success:

```
$silverpop->__soapCall('Login',
    array(array('USERNAME' => 'zzz', 'PASSWORD' => 'xxx')),
    array('uri' => 'SilverpopApi:Engageservice', 'soapaction' => '')
);
```

Comment: `$silverpop = new SoapClient('http://api1.silverpop.com/SoapApi?wsdl');`

Comment: Still getting the same thing.. any ideas?

Comment: try `var_dump($result)`.. does it have any error data? or are you getting any errors on the page?

Comment: nope - that suggests the request is being sent out just fine actually!: http://pastebin.com/ETh1unBw Still.. it'd be nice to see what the request actually was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to add a second parameter to SoapClient to get __getLastRequest() to work. eg.

```
$silverpop = new SoapClient('http://api1.silverpop.com/SoapApi?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
```